# Problem with reading files in Xamarin Forms "could not find file"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new in the Xamarin Forms and I wanna read and then write to XML file some data. I found the article about that in Xamarin documentation, here it is https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows. I wanna use File class. The problem is that I can't find the file "temp.txt" in the example project. So, I started looking for sth on the internet. I read that the file should be in the assets folder and the build type should be set to "AndriodAsset" (in the example project this file does not exist there). I did it but it doesn't work and I got an error "Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.companyname.myApp/files/.local/share/someData.xml"".
Here is my code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "someData.xml");
string data = File.ReadAllText(path); //here the program is stopping
```

Comment: use AssetManager to read Assets

Comment: Xamarin.Essentials has a cross-platform `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` method that can read Android Assets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android